# Correlation between ngOnInit and ionViewWillLoad lifecycle hook/event

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

It's been a couple of months since I'm using Ionic Framework ([ionic-angular](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#392-2017-11-08) **3.9.2 latest**) to build Progressive Web Apps. In the meantime, I've always wondered the difference between `ngOnInit` and `ionViewWillLoad`.

If I'm not wrong, I believe that `ngOnInit` is an [Angular lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) and it initializes the directive and component. *(Sets the directive/component's input properties.)*

`ionViewWillLoad` is an [Ionic navigation lifecycle event](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/), and it seems to get executed before `ionViewDidLoad` *(Everything has been already loaded)* event gets fired. It looks like `ionViewWillLoad` event has not added to NavController, and the documentation also has not updated yet.

As far as I know, the constructor gets called by the JavaScript engine, and it should be avoided using it for complex initializations. *([details: why you should avoid complex constructor logic](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/))*

For this reason, I've used `ionViewWillLoad` to set up the component after Ionic sets the input properties.

I'm not sure why, but `ionViewWillLoad` was the only event that worked without getting any errors.

```
export class UsernamePage {
  usernameControl: FormControl;

  constructor(private userService: UserServiceProvider){ }

  // No errors
  ionViewWillLoad() { this.createUsernameForm(); }

  // Errors
  ionViewWillEnter() { this.createUsernameForm(); }
  ionViewDidEnter() { this.createUsernameForm(); }
  ionViewDidLoad() { this.createUsernameForm(); }

  createUsernameForm() {
    this.usernameControl = new FormControl('',
    {
      validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)],
      asyncValidators: CustomValidator.username(this.userService)
    });
  }
}
```

Should I stick with using `ionViewWillLoad`? Or is it better to implement [OnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) interface? What's the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Note: For V3, I use the terms "hooks" and "events" interchangeably when referring to the lifecycle methods.*

From what I can tell, `ionViewWillLoad` is not one of the lifecycle hooks in the latest version of Ionic V3. I'd be curious to know specifically what errors you're seeing for the other life cycle events. But for now, I'm aiming this answer at a few underlying questions:

**1) What is the difference between Angular's `ngOnInit` and Ionic's `ionViewDidLoad`? Is one better than the other?**

Interestingly enough, there seems to be overlapping purpose between Angular's `ngOnInit` and `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hooks and Ionic's `ionViewDidLoad` and `ionViewWillUnload` lifecycle events (respectively). They are only called when a page is created or deleted (respectively), which may not happen as often as you think because of how Ionic tends to cache pages for a better mobile experience.

In child/sub components for V3, your only choice is to use the Angular lifecycle hooks. In page-level components for V3 (AKA components that are pushed/popped from a `NavController`) you can use them interchangeably, but I would just choose one or the other, not both, and be consistent. In Ionic V4, they made this choice for you by removing `ionViewDidLoad` and `ionViewWillUnload`.

**2) What is the difference between Angular's `ngOnInit` and Ionic's `ionViewWillEnter`? Is one better than the other?**

Firstly, these questions only apply to page-level components because Ionic Lifecycle events can only be used in page-level components ([V3 documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/#lifecycle-events)). Child/sub components do not know anything about Ionic Lifecycle Events because they aren't being pushed/popped by the `NavController` (this might be the reason why you were seeing errors?).

The major difference between these two particular events is the sequence in which they fire and how often they fire. When a page-level component is created, `ngOnInit` will fire before before `ionViewWillEnter`. However pages are not necessarily destroyed (and therefore will not be recreated later) unless they are popped off the navigation stack [(V3 documentation)](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/#view-creation).

> By default, pages are cached and left in the DOM if they are navigated away from but still in the navigation stack (the exiting page on a `push()` for example). They are destroyed when removed from the navigation stack (on `pop()` or `setRoot()`).

I wouldn't say that one is *better* than the other. You can implement both. Just be aware that `ngOnInit` may not fire as often/consistently as you'd expect. `ionViewWillEnter` fires whenever the page is about to enter and become the active page.

**For Ionic V4 (Angular)**

Lifecycle events are much more straightforward in V4. There are half as many Ionic lifecycle events and they don't overlap in functionality with Angular lifecycle events like I mentioned for v3. There are good explanations for each and [actual guidance](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle#guidance-for-each-life-cycle-method) around the [usage of Angular and Ionic lifecycle events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle)

The main takeaways are similar (and I believe applicable to V3).

> Pages are only removed from the DOM when they are "popped", for instance, by pressing the back button in the UI or the browsers back button.
>
> Because of this special handling, the `ngOnInit` and `ngOnDestroy` methods
>   might not fire when you would usually think they should.
>
> `ngOnInit` will only fire each time the page is freshly created, but not
>   when navigated back to the page. For instance, navigating between each
>   page in a tabs interface will only call each page's `ngOnInit` method
>   once, but not on subsequent visits. `ngOnDestroy` will only fire when a
>   page "popped".

Comment: Although, I don't work with the Ionic framework anymore, thank you for clarification to help other viewers.

Answer (score 2):

In Ionic 3 you should use

```
  ionViewWillEnter () {
    console.log('fired every time you enter the view');
  }
```

it should be used for tasks you want to do every time, like accessing data that may have changed or updating a table.

```
ionViewDidLoad () {
    console.log('not fired on entering a view that is already cached');
  }
```

is a good hook for page init tasks that do not need to be fired every time, as it is not fired on entering a view that is already cached.